# Kendo Grid - Export to Excel Bug when filtering grid

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, telerik, grid, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI v2016.3.1118

I have a grid that I have a default filter on, so that on datasource load, the grid automatically filters the data based on a users default site in the database.

I am using Kendo's provided Export to Excel from `proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"`

The bug I have discovered is that, after loading the grid, if I (as a user) click to clear all filters so that all the data is displayed in the grid, and then click export to excel...the only data that gets exported is the data matching the original filter.

This only seems to be a bug related to a default filter applied to the grids datasource on load.

If i leave it with no filter at all, and export, i get all the data. Or, if i add a filter after grid load, manually from the screen, it correctly exports the filtered selection.

But, a default filter seems to not be getting cleared, even when I have clicked clear all and see the data change on screen.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?

Update:

I have an example mocked here, using kendo's own provided example. I added a clear filters button like I am using and have replicated the problem here: https://dojo.telerik.com/AZUce

Comment: I have the same problem.
Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In version Kendo UI R2 2018, May 16, 2018, it has been resolved the bug.

"Removing a filter applied in the configuration will still export to excel filtered data in a Grid."